# docker ps -a not showing my container

Tags: docker

I have a strange issue on one of my Ubuntu 14.04 servers, running docker 1.4.1 (yes I know it's an old version...).

I'm 100% sure this server should have one container running, but the "docker ps -a" command shows nothing...

If I check the bash history, I can find that the container ID was "577376a8f3af"

The strange part is if I list the content of the /var/lib/docker/containers folder, I can see a folder nammed 577376a8f3af5812dda53ca90e642d50f1b230a8311443d9f681d9dd0241f9f1 which I'm pretty sure is my lost container...

Is there anyway to restore it ?

Thank you very much

Comment: What was your command to start the container?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. aufs was completely broken with my kernel version and Docker needed it. I think I've upgraded the kernel one day and something went wrong, but I only discovered it after a reboot...

To fix this, I've installed a new docker server on Digitalocean. Luckily for me, if you install it using the "One-click App" image, it will install docker with aufs support enabled. Then I stopped docker service and deleted everything in /var/lib/docker on this new server.

I've moved the content of /var/lib/docker from my broken server to the new one and restarted the docker service. It takes about 5 minutes to restart because docker was calculating checksums.

Finally I was able to see my container with the "docker ps -a" command, I've committed the image and pushed it to the docker hub for a deployment on a new server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried upgrading docker, fixed it by manually specifying to use the devicemapper storage driver as a docker daemon argument: `-s devicemapper`.

See also: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/

Comment: I'd recommend converting to overlay2 if that's an option.

Comment: I have no clue if that would work. Frankly, I just tried and errored different storage engines and this one happened to do so.

Comment: It's a migration, you'll lose all containers and images during the process (so save them in a registry/compose file). It also depends on a 4.x kernel. Devicemapper is seen on the rhel/centos environments, but with 7.4 they finally added overlay2 support.